# Multiple aggregate calculations by field value

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-python-console, aggregate-points

I want to count the number of geometries on Layer B within 30m of the geometry on Layer A. How can I repeat the calculations in the Field Calculator multiple times, so that I have a count for each value in field b1 of Layer B?
I know a little bit of python, but have used it very little in QGIS.
I want to repeat the following expression in the Field Calculator; there are about 30 categories in field b1.

```
 array_length( 
  overlay_nearest('layer_B',
   $id ,
   filter:= "field_b1"=1
   limit:=-1,
   max_distance:=60
   )
  )
```

Comment: You mention the Field Calculator: does this mean you want to create 30 fields/columns to provide the count for each category?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: If you want 30 columns, you should repeat this expression in each column definition, with the expected filter value. Using Virtual Fields will make sure they are updated if the geometry change

Comment: I agree.I was asking if anyone knows of a way to do it with less effort.

Comment: Possibly a pyggis script, but if it's only to do it once, I don't think you'll would spare much time